# Quartz not firing Triggers

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am facing an issue in quartz using `2.2.2.RELEASE` version, the job has been scheduled but it didn't get fired on time even there was 37 job scheduled but none of them get fired, all of they supposed to be fired on 5 Sep but they didn't get fired on 7 Sep also, the interesting thing is in quartz table next fire time is showing 5 Sep even on 7 Sep, Once I scheduled one new job all of them get updated.

#### Config

````
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.job-store-type =jdbc
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
# Using JobStoreTX
# Configuring JDBCJobStore with the Table Prefix
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix =SERVICE_QRTZ_
org.quartz.dataSource.myDs.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDs.maxConnections = 15
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=schedulerFactoryBean ```
````

Comment: Can you post the configuration

Comment: Added, please check, and let m know if some more info required

Comment: Is this multi instance environment?.Because I see the isClustered set to true.Because sometimes the job can be run by another instance so if you are debugging one instance the job can be picked by other.

Comment: Yes, it is a multi-instance environment, Actually We stored all fired trigger in mongo,so later we can debug it, whether the trigger has been fired or not,I believe either it is a single environment or multi-environment whenever trigger has been fired next fired time updated